# sequelize raw query, format of columns

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

In a raw query I want to know the definition of each resulting column, in particular the format. Is that possible using the API?

```
sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM `someTable`", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
  .then(rows=> {
        rows.forEach( row=>{
            for (col in row) {
                 let column=row[col];  // Is column a string, a date, a float ???
            }
        }
  })
```

Comment: Not possible, but you can use something like `SHOW FIELDS FROM tablename`, store it in variable, then get its value when you need it in your actual query.